# Interesting Functional Equations (Just for Fun)

Tags: recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

Here are a few functional equations that I made up that I thought that the math SE community would enjoy.

Just so everybody knows, I don't "need help" with these problems - they are simply for the enjoyment of anybody who is interested, and they all have non-constant solutions.

Have fun!

$$f(x+1)^2-4f(x)^2=f(2x+1)+2f(2x)$$
$$g(x)+g(x+1)=x+2$$
$$h(x)+h(x+1)=h\bigg(\sqrt{x^3+x^2-2x+1}\bigg)$$

Comment: Hm... is it just me, or do the last two functional equations look peculiarly easy to solve?

Comment: Oh... never mind, that last one looks much scarier now.

Comment: I don't know, give 'em a try! The second one was designed to look easy... *laughs menacingly*

Comment: ._. second one honestly didn't seem *that* bad...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Whoops, yeah... not hard at all. I meant to add the condition that it can't be a polynomial, but... whoops?

Comment: Can't be a polynomial? :-) Why would I ever assume something like that when I can make it $1000$ times more complicated, just the way you like it?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Lol, fair enough! XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions to (1) include $f(x) = 0$, $f(x) = -1$, and $f(x) = \dfrac{r^x}{r-2}$ where (if you want real solutions) $r > 0$ and $r \ne 2$.

(2) is an inhomogeneous linear equation, so the general solution is a particular solution plus the general solution of the homogeneous equation.  Yanko found a particular solution $g(x) = \frac{x}{2} + \frac{3}{4}$.  The homogeneous equation
$$ g(x) + g(x+1) = 0 $$
has general solution
$$ g(x + n) = (-1)^n g(x), \ n \in \mathbb Z,
\; x \in [0,1)$$
with $g$ defined arbitrarily on $[0,1)$.  If you want the solution to be continuous, require $\lim_{x \to 1-} g(x) = -g(0)$.

Comment: Mind I ask how you came up with $(1)$, if it wasn't by chance? And interestingly, as you can see in my answer, a subset of the solutions of $(1)$ reduce down to $(2)$.

Comment: I looked for solutions of the form $a r^x$.

Answer (score 4):

For $(1)$, note that

$$(f(x+1)+2f(x))(f(x+1)-2f(x))=f(2x+1)+2f(2x)$$

One subset of solutions requires

$$f(x+1)+2f(x)=0$$

By setting $f(x)=2^xg(\pi x)$, this comes down to

$$g(\pi x+\pi)=-g(\pi x)$$

Which has a general Fourier series solution

$$g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1}\cos((2n+1)x)+b_{2n+1}\sin((2n+1)x)$$

And thus,

$$f(x)=2^x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1}\cos((2n+1)\pi x)+b_{2n+1}\sin((2n+1)\pi x)$$

---

For $(2)$, let $g(x)=\frac14+\frac12x+f(\pi x)$ to get

$$f(\pi x)=-f(\pi x+\pi)$$

You could consider a Fourier series as the solution for this, mainly,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1}\cos((2n+1)x)+b_{2n+1}\sin((2n+1)x)$$

And thus,

$$g(x)=\frac14+\frac12x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1}\cos((2n+1)\pi x)+b_{2n+1}\sin((2n+1)\pi x)$$

Comment: Oh nice you generalized my solution using my trick!

Comment: @yanko No longer requires $g(x)$ to be differentiable in $(2)$, so... o.o

Comment: nice! good job!

Comment: Oh, come on... they all have closed-form solutions! Number one was satisfied by $x2^x$, number two was linear, and number three has the solution $\ln \frac{x^2-1}{x}$! Why did you have to do infinite series?! D:<

Comment: @Nilknarf It should be simple enough tasks finding particular coefficients such that the resulting series comes down to those particulars. If you wish to work those out yourself, you may wish to look up the Clausen functions. And are you assuming continuity/differentiability? It is often the case that a function can satisfy those equations you posed without being continuous (mainly at the integers), or if they were continuous, not differentiable almost everywhere (Weierstrass functions).

Comment: @Nilknarf If you want trivial solutions, set $a_n=0$ and $b_k=0$ for $n>N$ and $k>K$. You'll then find some nice solutions to your functional equations which are generally not the solutions you originally asked for.

Answer (score 1):

For (2)

> derivative both sides twice you have $g''(x)+g''(x+1)=0$ now I guessed that $g''(x)=0$ so $g'(x)$ is constant satisfying $g'(x)+g'(x+1)=1$ so $g'(x)=1/2$ so $g(x)=1/2x+c$ and is satisfying $g(x)+g(x+1)=x+2$ we conclude that $c=0.75$. so $g(x)=1/2x+0.75$ satisfying the equation.

Comment: Why must $g''(x)=0$?  What if $g''(x)$ is periodic $2$ and alternating?

Comment: no we don't must.. but that guess produced a solution... (he only asked for one solution.. didn't ask to classify them all)